# Moment js - days remaining - incorrect value coming back

Tags: javascript, momentjs

https://jsfiddle.net/yg4bk1wh/

I am trying to create a tool that reports the days remaining -

```
moment(1583884740000).diff(moment(), 'days')
```

but this is reporting incorrectly - almost as if the month index is not taken into consideration.

-- also if the days became negative - would want to obtain the value without the polarisation - so intead of "10 days remaining" -- it reads "finished 30 days ago"

-- https://www.calendar-12.com/days_between_dates

scenario 1
Start Date - February 12th
End Date - March 10th

total days between the two dates - 27 days
remaining days from now until end day - 33 days
^ campaign has yet to start

---

scenario 2
Start Date -January 6
End Date - March 10th

total days between the two dates - 64 days
remaining days from now until end day - 33 days

so the campaign has been running (64-33) = 31 days [totaldays-remaining days]
as such the campaign is (31/64 * 100) % complete [48%]

Answer (score 2):

In your jsfiddle, you're formatting the date wrong, which returns a wrong display date.
See snippet:

```js
console.log(moment(1583884740000).format('MMMM d YYYY'))
console.log(moment(1583884740000).format('MMMM D YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

`moment(1583884740000).format('MMMM D YYYY')` returns 'March 11 2020' which is the correct amount of days after today.

Answer (score 1):

In your line with days remaining, you are using the current date instead of your first date. `moment()` will return the current date and time.

`m[2] = ["days remaining",  moment(1583884740000).diff(moment(), 'days')];`

Put your first timestamp in and the result will be 27 days remaining, which is correct.

`m[2] = ["days remaining",  moment(1583884740000).diff(moment(1581465600000), 'days')];`

Here's a working fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd91mjs7/2/

---

To solve your text problem you could calculate your remaining days beforehand and change the text accordingly:

```
let daysLeft = moment(1583884740000).diff(moment(1581465600000);
let daysLeftLabel = daysLeft < 0 ? 'finished ago' : 'days remaining'

var m = [];
m[0] = ["moment(date1)", moment(1581465600000).format('MMMM D YYYY')];
m[1] = ["moment(date2)", moment(1583884740000).format('MMMM D YYYY')];
m[2] = [daysLeftLabel,  Math.abs(daysLeft), 'days')];
```

Note: `Math.abs()` returns  the absolute value, so that you don't get "-X days ago"

I'm not sure about the

> "10 days remaining" -- it reads "finished 30 days ago"

part though, in my example it would read "days ago 10" instead of "days remaining -10". You may need to change the logic yourself there.

Update: as @nsevens stated, you are also using the wrong date format. Instead of `d`, which gets you the day of the week, you should use `D` which returns the day of the month (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). I updated my example above.

Comment: I just realized that I simply assumed that you want the diff between date1 and date2 and not the actual remaining time from right now to just one of these dates. Please let me know if my assumption is wrong, I will delete my answer then since it wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: I kind of need both -- the "Total days between the two dates" --- and the days "remaining until the end date"